# Slow query with lot of joins and 'IN' statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a very slow query and I believe this is due to the 'IN' statement. The list of ids in the 'IN' statement can be very large, like 250+. This query will run for 2+ seconds every time, and that is too slow.

Is there a way to speed this up?

```
SELECT u.achternaam as achternaam, u.code as code, srt.niveaus as niveaus, srt.soortid AS soortid,IFNULL( scr.gehaald,'0')AS gehaald, IFNULL( scr.gespeeld,'0')AS gespeeld, IF( srt.niveaus =1,'n.v.t.', IFNULL(scr.huidigniveau,'0') )AS niveautext 
FROM gebruikers u 
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT scoreid,schoolcode, soortid, userid, gehaald, gespeeld, huidigniveau 
            FROM scores) scr
ON scr.userid = u.code              
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT soortid,niveaus,spelid,titel,verberg 
            FROM soorten 
            WHERE soortid IN (13,14,15,16,17,561,566,567,568,574,575,1,100,101,102,103,104,105,107,108,109,11,110,112,113,114,115,116,117,118,12,120,121,122,123,124,125,126,127,128,129,130,131,133,134,137,138,140,141,144,145)) srt
ON scr.soortid = srt.soortid
LEFT JOIN(SELECT spelnaam,spelid,vakid FROM spellen) g
ON srt.spelid=g.spelid
LEFT JOIN(SELECT vakid,vaknaam FROM vakken) vak
ON g.vakid=vak.vakid
WHERE u.groepsid='28' AND u.schoolcode ='1'  AND srt.verberg =0
ORDER BY achternaam,vak.vaknaam,g.spelnaam,srt.titel ASC
```

**result of Explain Select**:

[image: explain]

Comment: paste the query execution plan (explain select ....) please

Comment: without knowing anything about the data / mysql version - i would guess its because of the sub queries, They are easily written as real joins and you keep any indexing that applied to them. the large "IN" wouldnt cause a problem its the large chunk of un-indexed data left from joining a sub query

Comment: @guido I've added the results of explain select (didn't know about existance of that until know, thanks for that).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use subqueries, just join with the tables directly.

Note that the `srt.verberg = 0` test should be in the `ON` clause, not the `WHERE` clause. When you use a `LEFT JOIN`, all the conditions on the second table should be in `ON`, unless you're testing for the `NULL` that results from not finding a match.

```
SELECT u.achternaam as achternaam, u.code as code, srt.niveaus as niveaus, srt.soortid AS soortid,IFNULL( scr.gehaald,'0')AS gehaald, IFNULL( scr.gespeeld,'0')AS gespeeld, IF( srt.niveaus =1,'n.v.t.', IFNULL(scr.huidigniveau,'0') )AS niveautext 
FROM gebruikers u 
LEFT JOIN scores scr
ON scr.userid = u.code              
LEFT JOIN soorten srt
ON scr.soortid = srt.soortid
    AND srt.soortid IN (13,14,15,16,17,561,566,567,568,574,575,1,100,101,102,103,104,105,107,108,109,11,110,112,113,114,115,116,117,118,12,120,121,122,123,124,125,126,127,128,129,130,131,133,134,137,138,140,141,144,145)
    AND srt.verberg = 0
LEFT JOIN spellen g
ON srt.spelid=g.spelid
LEFT JOIN vakken vak
ON g.vakid=vak.vakid
WHERE u.groepsid='28' AND u.schoolcode ='1'
ORDER BY achternaam, vak.vaknaam, g.spelnaam, srt.titel ASC
```

Also, make sure you really need to use `LEFT JOIN` rather than `INNER JOIN`. `LEFT JOIN` should only be used when you want the result to include rows from the first table that have no matches in the second table. `INNER JOIN` performance is usually better, so you should use that whenever appropriate.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! The query is now so much faster and thanks for the great explanation! (from 4 seconds to 0.39 seconds!)

Answer (score 1):

You are joining on subquery results, I would expect the execution planner to have problems with making that efficient. Just join in the tables:

```
select
  u.achternaam as achternaam,
  u.code as code,
  srt.niveaus as niveaus,
  srt.soortid as soortid,
  ifnull(scr.gehaald,'0') as gehaald,
  ifnull(scr.gespeeld,'0') as gespeeld,
  if(srt.niveaus = 1, 'n.v.t.', ifnull(scr.huidigniveau,'0')) as niveautext 
from
  gebruikers u 
  left join scores scr on scr.userid = u.code
  left join soorten srt on srt.soortid IN (13,14,15,16,17,561,566,567,568,574,575,1,100,101,102,103,104,105,107,108,109,11,110,112,113,114,115,116,117,118,12,120,121,122,123,124,125,126,127,128,129,130,131,133,134,137,138,140,141,144,145)) and scr.soortid = srt.soortid and srt.verberg = 0
  left join spellen g on srt.spelid = g.spelid
  left join vakken vak on g.vakid = vak.vakid
where
  u.groepsid = '28' and u.schoolcode = '1'
order by
  achternaam,
  vak.vaknaam,
  g.spelnaam,
  srt.titel asc
```

Note: I moved the condition `srt.verberg = 0` into the join, having it in the `where` makes it work like an inner join.

Comment: This is also a good answer. I have accepted @Barmar answer because of his explanation. Thanks.